# split method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to split given String by every space.
So, class Test has source:text

```
 def create
        @test = Test.new(params[:test])
        @test.source = @test.source.split(/ /)
        #that usual code
```

And if I input something like

```
'A B C D'
```

The output is

```
'--- - A-B-C-D'
```

and behaves like usual string, so @test.source[0] gives '-'.

I want it to be array. 
I need it to access every word in my text input through its order, for example, @test.source[0] I want to return "A".

**UPD:**

Now I found out that 'serailize' method it is what I'm looking for, but

```
serialize :sources, Array
```

doesn't change anything

Comment: ok, it doesn't work because source declared as text. But how can I create an array?

Comment: You need to be clear on what the input is - probably a string of "A B C D"?  And on what the output is - probably an array of strings as ["--- -", "A-B-C-D"] BUT, I really don't know what your desired output is!

Comment: Google "how to create an array in ruby". Also, look here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_arrays.htm

Answer (score 3):

May be so??

```
 1.9.3-p374 :012 > "A B C D".split(" ")
  => ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

Comment: ok, that's my mistake that I tagged thsi post as ruby) no, the problem is little more specific to rails

Comment: Rails is written on ruby))) You can split text into array as I suggested and then you'll be able to access to every letter.

Comment: You actually can access to every letter of a String like it was an array: `"Bob"[2] #=> "b"`

Comment: Sure - ```1.9.3-p374 :014 > "Bob"[2] => "b"```

Comment: rails written on ruby, but not the database)

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
def create
        @test = Test.new(params[:test])
        @test.source = @test.source.split(" ")
```

Comment: no, I suppose that doesn't work because source column content was declared as "text" when I created a migration. But I can't find how to create column with arrays.

Comment: What is your source for this text? Because the answers provided work with strings. But if you are getting data from a URL or something, it is going to be different.